# Show Segue uses the wrong presentingViewController, and causes wrong navigation

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to fix up an edit segue (show in IB) where I can click the 'Edit report details' button on the toolbar and it will Show Segue towards the 'Configure Report' View controller.

However, if I click cancel, it goes all the way back to my login screen, because presentingViewController is a UINavigationController, even though it shouldn't be.

Here's the story board. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfvO9.png

Any ideas?

```
// MARK: Navigation
@IBAction func cancel(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways.
    let isPresentingInAddItemMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

    if isPresentingInAddItemMode {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        // In this mode (push presentation), we need to pop the view controller to get rid of it, rather than dismissing
        navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all I do in my code and it works.

```
@IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

How ever you may need to check for which segue identifier sent you first.

```
@IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
   if (segue.identifier == "Edit") {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
   } else if (segue.identifier == "Add") {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

This way it knows which one to follow. It also may depend on how you are segue to the view in the first place.